# How to pass data dynamic child component in react

Tags: autocomplete, redux, react-redux, parent-child

I am creating dynamic child components for a table.

### Parent Component

```
class SimpleView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onAutoChange = this.onAutoChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      columns: this.createcolumns(clone(this.props.tableInfo.columns)),
      dataList: this.props.data,
      result: []
    };
  }
  createcolumns(columns) {
    const editColumnRender = (text, record, index) =>
      <AssingCell
        index={index}
        columnsKey={columns[3].key}
        onAutoChange={this.onAutoChange}
      />;
    columns[3].render = editColumnRender;
    return columns;
  }

  onAutoChange(value){
    this.props.fetchDrivers('',value);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
     if(nextProps.driversData && nextProps.driversData.message === 'SUCCESS' && i<1)
   {
      this.setState({driversResult: nextProps.driversData.data});
     i=i+1;
   }
 }

  render() {
    const { columns, dataList, loading } = this.state;

    return (
      <TableWrapper
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={dataList}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a child component named AssingCell. There is a modal button inside the button. There is also one autocomplete in Modal. This.props.onAutoChange is called during every call. In this section, data is fetched from the server. How can I send this data to the child component?

Or how else can I do this?

Comment: Please post some more snippet, it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @VivekN The problem is. How can I make a server side autocomplete on a dynamically generated child component?